# Transfer whole Linux system and grub settings to 2nd drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have system partition on /dev/xvda1 (slow disk) and just added SSD attached as /dev/xvdb.

How to fully transfer Linux system to /dev/xvdb and retire /dev/xvda1 without using the console?

1. Transfer all the files - should I use `tar` or `cpio`?
2. Reconfigure grub - I found some instructions telling me to edit `/etc/default/grub`, but this doesn't set the root device anywhere. What gives?

Anything else needed?

Comment: Http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/cloning. Take care to use the uuid labels of the disks. They will be preserved when cloning.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a cloning tool like **Clonezilla**. All you have to do is to boot form the CD and follow the instructions. It does require some basic understanding of the anatomy of your system, but all-in-all it is the easiest way to do it. All files will be transferred, as well as GRUB. The partitions will be resized accordingly.

Comment: the machine has no CD-ROM drive and no keyboard. I need to do this strictly from the root shell

Comment: Then look at what commands and tools Clonezilla uses and do the same. All the tools are freely available. Exercise it on a different computer.

Answer (score -2):

I would check out rsync.

I would also recommend using a virtualization suite if you are going to move. That will make life a lot simpler for the future.

Comment: rsync isn't going to be particularly helpful for GRUB.